# Youtube fmt_stream_map gives error with region restricted videos

Tags: php, video

My server is in US and the video I am trying to get its info is allowed in US.
But I don't know why the method:

```
File_Get_Contents('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id='.$vidID );
```

doesn't work with any video has a region restriction, even if my server is not within the blocked areas.

Here is the video ID: a94xCZkDyc0

any ideas ?

Note: I tried to embed the video and it works fine but I can not retrieve the fmt stream map info.

Comment: This is likely to be an ongoing issue - even if your server is located in the US, it doesn't mean YouTube knows this. IP geo mappings are only ever 98% accurate. The other option is that Google simply blocks any requests with headers/user agents that it doesn't like.

Comment: I can play the video in an embedded form without any problem, I can not understand the reason behind that I can not retrieve the video info. I keep receiving the video is not available in [reason] only when I use file_get_contents. I drive me crazy as i couldn't figure out the reason.