# How to use my website ip address as a proxy?

Tags: php, proxy

I have a website where I can embed some youtube videos, but some videos are region restricted. I found a video that is allowed in US, my server is in US but still it doesn't work. After some investigation I figured out that Google thinks my website IP is in Brazil and therefore it blocks this video from playing in my website. What I want to do is to use my website IP as a proxy to request the video info using cURL

As I tried to use file_get_contents but i received nothing due to the region restriction which shouldn't happen to me because my server is in US not Brazil.

So, as a working around I tried to use my Website IP as a proxy which seems a bit weird because if google thinks my website IP is from Brazil sill making the same IP as a proxy will cause the same problem, but I want to give it a shot and see what will happen. As I tested my IP on man websites and all of them confirmed it is from US.

If anyone knows what is the reason behind this issue please, let me know.

I just want to know how to use my website IP as a proxy.

Thanks.
(I edited the question so I can elaborate and give more details)

Comment: Looks related to your other question [Youtube fmt_stream_map gives error with region restricted videos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279193/youtube-fmt-stream-map-gives-error-with-region-restricted-videos) (Keyword: restricted).

Comment: Yes, I investigated the problem and I found that for some reason google thinks I am from Brazil and I found some pages in Portuguese.

Comment: why some people gave me minus ?
What is wrong ?

Comment: no idea, I can't speak for the others. I didn't downvote the question. There could be many reasons why, so you'll need to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a what's called a forward Proxy, here is how you can make one very easily with apache :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# Enable forward proxy
ProxyRequests On
# Add "Via" header
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Proxy>

ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-error.log"
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

This goes into the default config file of your Apache, usually under :

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try your solution

Comment: You're welcome mate. Let us know if you have any trouble with that